# creating subfolder when creating parent folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

would it be possible to add in sub folders (with preset names) when creating a new folder via script

```
function createFolder() {
  const parent = DriveApp.getFolderById("1Cyki5N4HBaKWo7fs1Ye3PVjl8KeEdOPs");
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Detailing');
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  range.getValues().forEach(function (row, index) {
    // Consider checking if this r & c has a formula in the equal size array from getFormulas()
    if(row[0]) {
      var newLink = getLinkForFolderName_(parent, row[0]);
      // Use the current array index to write this formula in only the correct cell.
      range.offset(index, 0, 1).setFormula(
        "HYPERLINK(\"" + newLink + "\", \"" + row[0] + "\")"
      );
    }
  });
}

function getLinkForFolderName_(root, name) {
  var folder;
  const search = root.getFoldersByName(name);
  if (search.hasNext()) {
    folder = search.next();
    if (search.hasNext())
      console.warn("Multiple folders named '" + name + "' in root folder '" + root.getName() + "'");
  }
  else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
  ["Quote", "Detailing", "Delivery"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
}
}
```

what I would like to happen is when the new parent folder is created, subfolders labelled Quote, Detailing, Delivery to be created at the same time

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
}
else
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
```

#### To:

```
} else {
  folder = root.createFolder(name);
  ["Quote", "Detailing", "Delivery"].forEach(function(e) {
    folder.createFolder(e);
  });
}
```

- In this modification, using `folder` in your script, the subfolders with the folder names of "Quote", "Detailing", "Delivery" are created in `folder`.
- From your script, I'm worried that you might disable V8 runtime. So I used `forEach(function(e) {})`. If you are using V8 runtime, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    ["Quote", "Detailing", "Delivery"].forEach(e => folder.createFolder(e));
  ```

Comment: thanks @Tanaike the solution worked but now the hyperlink that's inserted into the cell comes up as undefined

Comment: @banksie Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `now the hyperlink that's inserted into the cell comes up as undefined`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested the modified script, the hyperlink is created with the URL of the created parent folder. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For example, when you deleted `return folder.getUrl();`, such issue occurs. Can you confirm this again? And, can you provide your current whole script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: i have updated the post with the complete folder script thank you for your help

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by putting return folder.getUrl(); into the script, thank you for your help